# Swift remove UIview immediately and show animation duration 1sec at another place

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3, swift4

i want to remove UIView from superview immediately and show that view at another place by animation

i try this

```
    mView.removeFromSuperview()
    
    mView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 121, height: 58)

    self.view.addSubview(mView)
    
    UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 1, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
        self.mView.alpha = 1
    }, completion: nil)
```

this code will remove mView and add mView at the same time duration 1 sec
but i need remove mView immediately

maybe i need update my self.view after   mView.removeFromSuperview() ?

thanks

i tried this

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    self.infoWindow.alpha = 0
    
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let data = marker.userData as! [String : Any]

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (data["latitude"] as! Double), longitude: (data["longitude"] as! Double))

    self.infoWindow = CustomGMSInfoWindow(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 121, height: 58))
    self.infoWindow.center = mapView.projection.point(for: location)
    self.infoWindow.center.y = (infoWindow.center.y) - 65
    self.infoWindow.frame = CGRect(infoWindow.frame.origin.x, infoWindow.frame.origin.y, infoWindow.frame.width, infoWindow.frame.height)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        self.infoWindow.alpha = 1.0
    }



    return false
}
```

Comment: run `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` after you have removed it i think

Comment: its not work, i tried it

Comment: Do you want it to animate **moving and fading** from one location to another? Or do you want it to "snap" disappear and then immediately "fade in" in another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to remove / re-add `mView`. All you need to do is set its `.alpha` to Zero, change its frame, and then animate the `.alpha` back to 1 (will cause it to "fade in".

```
    // set alpha to Zero (invisible)
    self.mView.alpha = 0.0
        
    // set its new frame
    self.mView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 121, height: 58)
    
    // "fade in"
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        self.mView.alpha = 1.0
    }
```

Here's a complete example. Each time you tap, the red `mView` will disappear and then "fade in" at a random location:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let mView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mView.backgroundColor = .red
        mView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 121, height: 58)
        view.addSubview(mView)
        
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.doAnim))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        
    }
    
    @objc func doAnim() -> Void {
        
        let x = CGFloat.random(in: 0...(view.frame.size.width - 121))
        let y = CGFloat.random(in: 0...(view.frame.size.height - 58))

        // set alpha to Zero (invisible)
        self.mView.alpha = 0.0
        
        // set its new frame
        self.mView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 121, height: 58)
        
        // "fade in"
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.mView.alpha = 1.0
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit: *the original question posted was not the actual question***

Here is your posted code, with a couple changes. Read through the comments:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    // (1) - if you are creating a NEW view at (3),
    //  remove this view first
    //self.infoWindow.alpha = 0
    self.infoWindow.removeFromSuperview()

    // (2) - not needed
    //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let data = marker.userData as! [String : Any]

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (data["latitude"] as! Double), longitude: (data["longitude"] as! Double))

    // (3) - create a NEW view
    self.infoWindow = CustomGMSInfoWindow(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 121, height: 58))
    self.infoWindow.center = mapView.projection.point(for: location)
    self.infoWindow.center.y = (infoWindow.center.y) - 65

    // (4) - this is setting the frame to itself - you don't need this
    self.infoWindow.frame = CGRect(infoWindow.frame.origin.x, infoWindow.frame.origin.y, infoWindow.frame.width, infoWindow.frame.height)

    // (5) - you created a NEW view, so you need to set its alpha here
    self.infoWindow.alpha = 0.0
    
    // (6) - and you need to add it as a subview... I'm assuming it needs to be added to the mapView
    mapView.addSubview(self.infoWindow)
    
    // (7) if this doesn't fade in the new view...
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        self.infoWindow.alpha = 1.0
    }

    // (8) try it like this - wait 5/100ths of a second before starting the fade-in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.05, animations: {
        self.infoWindow.alpha = 1.0
    })

    return false
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks your reply,   i use alpha in  func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool { }. but still  dismiss and show at 1 sec , this  GMSdelegate is for google map. it show  infowindow when i tap different marker. is this delegate a  problem?

Comment: @saint - I'm not sure what you are asking. Did this not answer your question? Or, are you now asking a new question?

Comment: @saint - in the future, if you post here on Stack Overflow, ***post your actual question.*** It's very frustrating to offer an answer as help, only to see a comment of *"well, that didn't work because it wasn't really my question"*. See the **Edit** in my answer.

Comment: hi @DonMag,  Sorry its my fault. your code in viewdidLoad is work, and your edit answer is work too. thanks  ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Run after your animation:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: i tried it but not work.  i put it under removeFromSuper or animation not work.